# Extracting a particular String in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file maned fil1.txt, and the contents of the files are:-

```
./pub/index.html                                                                           ./manifest.bak
./manifest.rel                                                                             ./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/node.idf
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcReprocessASNManifest/flow.xml.bak
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcReprocessASNManifest/node.ndf
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcReprocessASNManifest/flow.xml
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml.bak
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/node.ndf
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
```

I want to extract all the lines which i having flow.xml at the end and save it to different file.
The Output file should be:--

```
 ./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcReprocessASNManifest/flow.xml
    ./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `grep`:

```
$ grep 'flow\.xml$' file > output
$ cat output
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcReprocessASNManifest/flow.xml
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
```

`$` indicates end of line, so this is checking all lines that end with `flow.xml`. Also, `.` is escaped to represent literal dot, and not a regex meaning "any character" ([thanks Jojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903723/extracting-a-particular-string-in-shell-script/21903806?noredirect=1#comment33171862_21903806)).

Comment: I think you should escape `.` character in your pattern. Now it will match also strings ending with `flowaxml`, `flowbxml` etc.